# Ember allow certain requests to pass mirage to internet

Tags: ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I am using ember-cli-mirage and I want to mock some requests, but allow others to actually call out to the internet.  Is there a way to tell mirage requests that match a certain pattern should be ignored and allowed to actually hit the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is mirage passthrough which allows you to whitelist paths to be allowed the get to the network.

As seen here http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/server-configuration/